# How to get both text and value from kendo combobox using TypesScript(angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-combobox

I need to get both text and value from the kendocombox box onchange event. But i am able to get only the value field. Text is not displaying.

**HTML:**

```
 <kendo-combobox [data]="taxRatesource" [placeholder]="'Select'" [textField]="'text'"
                 [valueField]="'value'" (valueChange)="taxRateGridChange($event)"
                 [(ngModel)]="datachild.intTaxRateCode">
                </kendo-combobox>
```

**TS:**

```
taxRateGridChange(event) {
const textVal = event;
}
```

const textVal contains only the value , but want text too. Kinldy help to sort out this issue.

Comment: In general, selects or combos return a value of selected option. Why you are not trying to find a selected entity from your datasource array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally selects or combos return a value of selected option. But you can find selected value from your dataSource.

```
  taxRateGridChange(value) {
    let textVal;
    if (value) {
      const selectedOption = this.dataSource.find((entity) => entity.value === value);
      textVal = selectedOption ? selectedOption.text : null;
    } else {
      textVal = null;
    }
  }
```